# Creating new file with Node.js and Express

Tags: command-line

I'm trying to learn how to use Node.js and its packages. I'm in my Command Prompt (I'm on Windows), changed directory to my project folder. Then I installed the Express package:

```
npm install express --save
```

The npm installed the Express package. Now, while I'm still in the directory, I'm trying to create a new file:

```
touch index.js
```

But the file isn't created and I'm getting the following message:

```
'touch' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Why is that? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`touch` is no Windows command.

In [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/502374/equivalent-of-linux-touch-to-create-an-empty-file-with-powershell), they suggest this as an equivalent:

```
echo $null >> filename
```

Answer (score 0):

`touch` is a Unix command that creates an empty file (or updates its timestamp if it doesn't exist).  It has nothing to do with Node specifically.

Most Unix distributions (including OSX) will have `touch` installed by default.  So I suspect you're on a Windows machine....

Comment: "So I suspect you're on a Windows machine" - Well, I actually mentioned that I'm on Windows in my question :) Still, thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Ah, so you did...sorry I missed that detail.